Окно pywebview блокирует другие окна
С помощью Python сделал простенькую программу с графической оболочкой (tkinter) и двумя кнопками, подключил библиотеку - pywebview.
При нажатии на кнопки открываются через webview.create_window разные сайты. Проблема в том, что при создании одного окна, блокируется окно root и пока сайт не закроешь, он не даст открыть например параллельно с ним другой.
Как решить эту проблему?
Хотел бы рассмотреть возможность работы с главным окном, пока открыто окно сайта.
Причём необходима именно библиотека pywebview, другие варианты некорректно отображают сайт...

А зачем вам две графические оболочки, если вы все можете сделать в pywebview?

Графическая оболочка одна - tkinter. Есть главное окно, внутри него 2 кнопки, при нажатии на одну открывается допустим гугл, при нажатии на другую яндекс, но при открытии окна с гугл главное окно блокируется и с ним нельзя взаимодействовать. Как обойти этот момент? Дело в том, что программа другая у меня, поэтому привожу такой простой пример, где чётко выражена проблема, которая мешает

"pywebview использует собственный графический интерфейс для создания окна веб-компонента: WinForms в Windows, Cocoa в macOS и QT или GTK в Linux" смотри документацию https://pywebview.flowrl.com/guide/.

Всё, я понял о чём Вы.. Честно говоря только начинаю, много таких моментов упускаю к сожалению. Получается, что в моей ситуации, будет корректно переписать всю программу в графической оболочке pywebview? Потому что иначе не встрою его в tkinter, чтобы свою проблему решить...

Почему, можно, привязать молоток к топору с помощью мультипроцессинга.

Окно вашей программы отрисовывается в единственном потоке, операция создания окна вероятно является блокирующей операцией(пока она не завершиться выполнение не продолжиться) из-за чего основное окно не обновляется. Следовательно стоит эту операцию перенести в другой поток что бы окно программы продолжало нормально отрисовываться. Threading вам в помощь.

@kristal Спасибо огромное Вам за пояснение! Да, Threading использую в приложении для обновления некоторых данных, поэтому лишнего не будет)) Просто в голову не пришло, что окно блокирует поток основной, теперь понял в каком направлении работать =)
